# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'generateAuthority')

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, typescript-typings

I'm encountering a TypeError in the RedirectClient module of my Next.js application. The specific error message is: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'generateAuthority')". I believe the issue lies in the generateAuthority method of the Authority class.

I'm using the RedirectClient module, which relies on the Authority class to generate the authority. However, when the code reaches the line where generateAuthority is called, it throws the aforementioned error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPXnE.png)

Expected outcome:
I expect the generateAuthority method to be accessible and properly executed without encountering the TypeError. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Note: Please let me know if there's any additional information or code snippets needed to assist in diagnosing and resolving the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.